# hide or display field based on the checkbox value. if check box is selected display the label and field if not selected hide itin playframework

Tags: html, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a form where i have to display certain fields based on the value of the checkbox.

below is the code in my view

```
        @checkbox(
        userModelForm("isStudent"),
        '_label -> <font color = "grey"> Student</font>,
        '_showConstraints -> false
    )
```

if this checkbox is selected i need to display the following input text if not this should be hidden

```
        @inputText(
            userModelForm("StudentId"),                
            '_label -> <font color = "grey" > Student Id </font> ,  'class -> "form-control",
            '_help -> "Realtors, please enter Your Student id.",
            '_error -> userModelForm.globalError
        )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the `@inputText` in a div that is hidden,`<div style="display: none;">` then use javascript to show/hide it. If you have many hidden divs, I would apply the styling from a .css file. (Inline isn't very good)

You will need to add an id to the checkbox.

```
        @checkbox(
    userModelForm("isStudent"),
    '_label -> <font color = "grey"> Student</font>,
    '_showConstraints -> false,
    'id -> "show-student-checkbox"
)
```

Then take a look at this, [get selected value of dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript)
You will then have to write `if` tests that unhides the div.

Take a look at this aswell if you are unsure about hiding + unhiding [divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14092940/javascript-how-to-hide-unhide-div)

Comment: Thanks it works good. The combination of div tag and hiding and unhiding worked well.

Comment: Please select this as the accepted answer if it solved your problem. Thanks.